# How can I assign new values to 3 params (eg XYZ) in the same statement?

Tags: python, scripting

I have this code:

```
import bpy

# Reset 3D Cursor Rotation
bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler[0] = 0
bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler[1] = 0
bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler[2] = 0
```

Instead of referencing the same main parameter on three lines, can I write this in a single line?

Pseudocode:

```
# My question refers to what's within the < > chars; I want to include all 3 params within the brackets

bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler[<0 to 2>] = 0
```

Comment: `bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler = [0] * 3` ? `bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler[0:3] = [0] * 3` ?

Comment: `cursor.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)` ??

Comment: @Gorgious and @RobinBetts All of these worked great except the one I liked the most, from Robin, which omitted the bpy class method (should be `bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)`). So please add it as an answer, Robin, so I can mark the question solved. Many thanks to you as well, Gorgious!

Comment: Well it's arguably not even a Blender related question, I suggest you read a bit on python basics if you want to continue playing with the API :)

Comment: @Gorgious Hmm. On the one hand I think you're absolutely right and looking at it from that angle, I totally agree. On the other hand, that would probably limit the type of code-related questions possible here (pertaining to things you want to do with Blender) down to very few. I don't know if there's a specific rule to the type of questions allowed in this regard but I definitely apologize if mine is to be considered too generic. The way I see it, Blender could actually be a great means to learn Python and therefore questions like this would arise.

Comment: @Gorgious Also, I did search the internet for an answer but didn't find a clue. The key problem is that it's not hard to search the web, or try to look among Python docs or tutorials, the problem is to ask the right question. I searched for "python set multiple parameters at the same time", which gave no answers anywhere. So I figured putting my question here was the fastest way. But again, I will of course respect any rules against that, if they exist. ;-)

Comment: Hehe no worries, if the crowd decides this question is off-topic, it will get closed. Seeing as it didn't, people didn't feel like it was off-topic. I didn't vote for it myself because I agree that this is a gray area. My suggestion still stands, though. I think you should start with a bit of basics, because the API can get a bit weird sometimes, if you have to learn the docs of the API AND python basics, you'll get blocked very often. You can read a bit a about for and while loops, tuples, lists, list comprehensions, data types and classes. That should get you started.

Comment: All fair points. Will try to push my Py game a bit further. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)
```